# How does the internet providers utilize or asign IPs

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ip, bittorrent

I'm asking because i used the iknowwhatyoudownload out of curiosity while at work, and i found some uninteresting torrents being downloaded (games and movies)

The internet provider is the same for work and home (in my case) and when i tested that website at home, it showed the very same torrents, the same IP, one of teh games was completly downloaded heh. Needless to say i used a different laptop and a different wifi.

So it got me thinking that maybe those torrents aren´t being downloaded from coworkers, but other people? Are we customers/users of this internet provider (my house, work and neighbors) somehow using the same net(?) or the same ip? Is it possible?

I live in a small town, only three internet providers (i use one of those) and outside the US (if that is useful).

Comment: Did you copy an iknowwhatyoudownload URL that includes an ip (`?ip=<your ip>`) such as `https://iknowwhatyoudownload.com/en/peer/?ip=8.8.8.8` instead of https://iknowwhatyoudownload.com

Comment: please focus your post to one clear, answerable question

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP has purchased blocks of IP addresses.
Unless you pay extra money you won't get a static IP address.

Instead there are DHCP pools, and computers are randomly assigned any free ip address in that pool.

The dhcp server also hands out a lease time, and after the lease time expires it will obtain a new ip address.  It is possible for the dhcp server to give your device the same ip address it had before, and in fact this is a common practice. However, it is still a random assignment.

The pool address and size is determined by your ISP.

So unless your company paid extra for a dedicated IP pool, all the IP addresses are shared amongst all the ISP customers.